# Is there an easier way to locate the vehicles Simeon wants?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Sometimes when Simeon sends a list of cars he wants, finding the more profitable ones can be tricky. But this latest list should have been the easiest cake-walk ever. FQ-2? Patriot? Fusilade? (Also Habanero and Gresley) Those are all the vehicles I get frustrated with when I'm trying to find *anything* good (be it *fast* or *valuable*).

However the game seems to have other ideas, as after 45 minutes of searching various areas, the Radius has overwhelmingly become Los Santos's most popular Hatchback/SUV. I literally counted 10 of them stopped in a single direction at a red light. Patriots have disappeared off the face of the earth, and the Sentinel XS seems to have replaced the Fusilade as the most popular 2-door coupe.

I just don't get it, the [GTA Wikia says the following under it's entry on the FQ-2's](http://gta.wikia.com/FQ_2) location online:

> The FQ 2 is a common vehicle, more so when it's being requested by
>   Simeon Yetarian for his Import/Export Garage.

Normally I'd agree with the first part of that quote. They *were* common. Very common. *Annoyingly* common. But the second part of that quote seems to be an outright lie based on what I've seen for the better part of the last hour. The entry on the Fusilade makes claims to similar frequent spawning bolstered by being requested.

I'm not going to waste any more time on this particular request from Simeon, as my time would be more profitably spent driving a Sanchez around the racetrack solo at this point (~$850/minute -vs- the maximum payout of ~$6720 for an FQ2 or Patriot). But is there some trick to more easily locating vehicles on Simeon's list?

Comment: Different vehicles spawn in different areas of the map. It also seems to matter what vehicle you are driving yourself as well.
Selling cars to Simeon is hardly lucrative at all, considering you have to find the car, respray it and drive to the corner of the map to deliver it. A single race can easily get you more cash if it's long enough (cash rewards are directly related to the length of a job).

Comment: Simeon can be somewhat profitable, but mostly if you just find the car in passing while doing other things, and depending on what he requests. But all of the cars in the list that prompted this question were so common, not finding one after 45 minutes is like going through Mt. Moon and not fighting a single Zubat. And I was not finding these cars while driving what I normally do when I see them everywhere.

Comment: You could look around the area where Michael lives (I don't know places by names), that's where I see patriots the most, but it is true that it's much harder to find anything if you're actively looking for it than if you were just going on with your business. The time it takes to respray the car and deliver it to the furthest corner of the map is a huge demotivator for me and he hardly pays more than Los Santos Customs would (take into account the cost of respraying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real "trick", the only thing you can do is check the wiki on where the frequent spawn points are. Another tactic that has worked for me is driving along the freeway, which has high traffic most of the day. Also if you check the lists sent by Simeon they usually include multiple similar vehicles so the list with FQ2 has many SUVs so be on the lookout for all the other SUVs you see and so on.

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less what I figured. But in that session there were **literally** *NO* hatchbacks/SUVs on the road except for the Radius. I joined a new session some time after typing the question and things were back to normal; FQ-2s, Patriots, and Fusilades were everywhere as per normal, and I had the same list from Simeon, so I have no clue what was going on with the situation that prompted the question.